# How can I change color of specific road in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to android.
I can add a map and add a point on it, but How can I change the color of a specific area of road in Google Maps?

Like the picture
[I wanna set OnClickListener for area 1 to 4 and create log for the position of that area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRbtL.jpg)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have latlng of the start point and destination point, you can draw polylines:

```
PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        polyOptions.width(10);
        polyOptions.add(startLatLng, latLngDestination);
```